# geom_bar tied exactly to x and y axis (without aggregating)

Tags: r, plot, charts, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a data frame with cols "x", "y" and ordinary rows ("x" and "y" can be treated as collections of numbers) . All I want is to plot a bar-chart with x tied to "x" and y tied to "y". Tried to use `geom_bar(stat='identity')` but it produce unexpected to me result - as I figured out it sums all the y-values of corresponding to bar x-value. When tried with `stat_identity(geom='bar')` the result was nice, but one problem occured: I can't figure out how to set fixed `alpha` for `stat_identity` (seems like it is automatically binds to the number of samples with corresponding to bar x-value).
Here are the examples:

```
ggplot() +
    geom_bar(data = xs, aes(x, y), stat = "identity", alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

```
ggplot() +
    stat_identity(data = xs, aes(x, y), geom = "bar", alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

So, once again, the **goal**: *to plot a bar-chart with x tied to "x" and y tied to "y"*. Hence the second example solves it, but there is an issue with `alpha` parameter.

UPDATE: File with test data can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z9rzdg9kjccnr2k/xs.csv?dl=0). Or as GitHub gist [there](https://gist.github.com/ArtemyB/aab09d7d377fbc51518cd43238416b30).

Comment: Could you provide some data? I can't reproduce your problem in the second plot.

Comment: @Haboryme, yes, of course. Wait a minute, please.

Comment: @Haboryme, updated the post. Link to data is in the end.

Comment: The with `geom_bar` is that is has `stack` as the default `position`.

Comment: @Axeman you're right. Set `position` to `"identity"` in the 1st example and got the same result as the 2nd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you want to do a `bar_plot` for data that contains multiple observations in `y` for a single `x`.
When using `geom_bar` it is simply summing (binning) the values.
When you use `stat_identity`it doesn't sum but it keeps the information of the number of occurrences for each values. Hence the alpha set to a much lower values for the extreme values (0 and 10 only have a single observation each).

So if you want to have a graph like the one you obtained with `stat_identity`, you need to drop the information regarding the number of occurrences. It's very easy since you only have repetition of a single value.

```
ggplot(data = xs[!duplicated(xs),], aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Thx for the answer. So it turns out that ggplot automatically finds a parameter which can be bound to the number of occurences? And this can't be avoided?

Comment: After fiddling a bit more with `ggplot` it seems the problem came from setting a value to alpha. If you don't set alpha you get the same plot that I did. But, frankly, I'm at loss to why alpha only reflects the distribution of the data (the alpha really is correlated to the number of occurrences)  when set to <1. I can't find any explanation in the documentation.

Comment: yes, the issue with alpha is still there. I need it to be 0.5, but it ignores it.

Comment: If you use the code I used to discard duplicates you can set `alpha=0.5` and it works fine.

Comment: @Dark_Clarl, you were just plotting a bunch of semi-transparent bars on top of each other, and at some x positions there were more bars. There is no spooky auto-mapping going on.

Comment: @Axeman: sometimes things are simple, just bars stacked on top of each other. Thanks, it confused me.

Comment: @Haboryme you're right, it works perfectly. Thanks a lot! :)